# Java Regex - Ilegal Repetition character

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

My regex is

```
(?:--|#|\/\*|{)
```

When i compile this using Pattern.complie() in java, I am getting **Illegal Repetitive Character **

I tested this regex

```
(a|\/\*|b)
```

When i compiled this, It shows no error.

Why does this occur ?

Comment: Is it not because of `{`? It is used to specify how many times should it be repeated. I would try it escaped: `(?:--|#|\/\*|\{)`

Comment: @GáborBakos That should be an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: That is not a real regex ... is it?

Comment: @StephenC yes it is... Bizarre but legal (after escaping the `{`). What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @fge ... *because* it is so bizarre.  Note ... I said "real" not "legal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [because of `{`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html). It is used to specify how many times something should it be repeated. For instance `x{2,4}` will match `x` repeated 2 (`xx`), 3 (`xxx`) or 4 (`xxxx`) times.

If you want regex to match `{` literal it needs to be escaped:

```
(?:--|#|\/\*|\{)
```

Comment: Usually you don't need to escape `{` if it's not followed by a digit and a `}`... It may solve the issue due to a Java particularity I'm not aware of, though: different flavors, different implementations.

Comment: @Robin: Yes, Java always treats `{` as the beginning of a quantifier and `[` as the beginning of a character class.  In fact, `[` retains that meaning *inside* a character class, in order to support its unusual set-intersection feature (`&&`).